# Possible to get actual token value?

Tags: parsing, antlr4, grammar

In Antlr4, let's say I have the following rule:

```
// grammar
root: TRUE eof;

// lexer
TRUE:       T R U E;
fragment T: [tT];
fragment R: [rR];
fragment U: [uU];
fragment E: [eE];
```

If the user enters in `true` the parse tree that it shows looks something like this:

```
  root
  /  \
TRUE EOF
```

But this gives me the token `TRUE` --

[image]

Is there a way to get the actual string value entered in, in this case `true`, respecting casing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each token comes with an index into the input stream. Use those to extract the original text. Note that `token.end` is inclusive , i.e. it points to the last character that belongs to that token.